# Java Swing: How to make the JComboxBox drop down list taller?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to make the "dropdown" (or "popup", I don't know how it's called) of a JComboBox taller on the screen?

By default, when I open my JComboBox I see, say, 7 out of 29 items, then I need to scroll.

What should I do so that I can see, say, 15 out of these 32 items? (or if the dropdown is, say, 150 pixels tall, how can I make it 300 pixels tall?)

I've read the Sun tutorial on JComboBox and the JavaDoc but I must have overlooked the method(s) to call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [setMaximumRowCount](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setMaximumRowCount%28int%29) method.

The [JComboBox tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) has some example code showing it in action.

Comment: indeed, thanks a lot, works perfectly fine.  I can only accept the answer in 6 minutes :)